# ng-repeat no me muestra la lista

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, web

estoy empezando a aprender AngularJS(Angular 1). realice un pequeño ejemplo y me muestra la lista :

HTML y JS:

```js
var app = angular.module(
 'flapperNews',
  []
);

app.controller(
 'MainCtrl', 
 
 [
  '$scope',
  function($scope) {
     $scope.test = 'Hello wrorld!';
     $scope.post = [
      'post 1',
      'post 2',
      'post 3',
      'post 4',
      'post 5'
     ];
  }
 ]
);
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App!</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="flapperNews" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div>
        {{post}}
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Pero si agrego el "np-repeat", no funciona :( Este es el código (mismo JS):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App!</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="flapperNews" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
        {{post}}
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Estoy siguiendo este tutorial (https://thinkster.io/tutorials/mean-stack/jumping-in-with-angular), a él le funciona tal cual, no se cuál será mi error

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agregala en español, el sitio es **Stack Overflow en Español**.

Comment: Hola @Jemonge! disculpa! no caché que estaba en la versión español jaja lo edito altiro! gracias!

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es por que estas llamando mal al `ng-repeat` para que funcione simplemente cambia `$scope.post` por `$scope.posts`, primero va el nombre que le quieras dar a tu `ng-repeat` y luego el nombre del objeto

```js
var app = angular.module(
 'flapperNews',
  []
);

app.controller(
 'MainCtrl', 
 
 [
  '$scope',
  function($scope) {
     $scope.test = 'Hello wrorld!';
     $scope.posts = [
      'post 1',
      'post 2',
      'post 3',
      'post 4',
      'post 5'
     ];
  }
 ]
);
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App!</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="flapperNews" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
        {{post}}
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pablo, gracias por tu respuesta, pero hasta que las preguntas no estan en el idioma oficial no solemos contestarlas. Esperemos que quien pregunto la traduzca, si no la pregunta sera cerrada.

Comment: @gbianchi ok gracias lo tendré pendiente.

Comment: muchísimas gracias por la respuesta @Pablo! era algo tan simple! :) ahora si funcionó! (y ya dejé en español la pregunta, era mi primera pregunta acá, gracias por la aclaración y perdón por el malentendido @gbianchi)

Comment: Con gusto ! espero servirle